# How to decide whether a number belongs to a series or not (deciding margin of error)?

Tags: java, margin

I have a dataset including 100 numbers.
And I have a test number.
My purpose is to decide weather this test number belongs to my dataset or not.

For this, I have to calculate a **max**, a **min** and a **margin of error** , these will indicate the interval of my dataset. But I don't know how to calculate those values. Is there anyone who can help me?

In the image below

[image]

black point are my dataset.

From these data, I will calculate the blue line and a margin ---> so that I can accept green ones and refuse red ones.

Comment: Google standard deviation adn xi test

Comment: It looks like you have test x,y. You have to determine what the acceptance criteria are based on your model. To me it look like the green points are outside your data set, only your model can say that actually I expect a linear relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking into these few examples. I think you will find all answers.

Basic things you need - Standard Deviation and Statistics:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/stdlib/StdStats.java.html

Linear Regression:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/LinearRegression.java.html